# CiviEvent custom data missing on confirmation page

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

I am testing out some custom data on CiviEvent under wordpress; on both the civicrm demo site and a live production site.  In both cases if you add a custom field with a checkbox to the profile for online registrations, for participant, the confirmation page confuses the data coming back.  I created a check box with 3 options (good, bad, ugly).  If I choose 2 of them (bad, ugly) then on the confirmation page I see the data as ", good,good".  If I choose the checkbox as (good) then I get "good, ,".  And if I select the checkboxes as (good, bad) then I get "good, good, ".  I each case I get the wrong set.

It seems to always use the first option no matter what I choose but it does return it in the correct index. Anyone have any suggestions to make this work?  Or has anyone looked into the issue already and solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that is a proper bug.
CiviCRM has a public issue tracking system, it's on https://issues.civicrm.org.

This bug was already found, see https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17129
It's solved in 4.7

If you really need it on 4.6 you can also find the patch there and try it on a test version of your site. No guarantees, so make sure you are not doing it on your production site.

If you would find another bug in the future and it can not be found via a search on issues.civicrm.org, you can help the whole community by creating an issue over there.